# How can I create a filegroup on SQL Server attaching a bare filename?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I'm trying to script a database creation from a Java program. I need to create 2 file groups, and link them to the database. In the example I can see in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-file-and-filegroup-options?view=sql-server-2017#examples), I only see examples with paths, like in this case:

> ### B. Adding a filegroup with two files to a database
>
> The following example creates the filegroup `Test1FG1` in the
>   AdventureWorks2012 database and adds two 5-MB files to the filegroup.
>
> ```
> USE master
> GO
> ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
> ADD FILEGROUP Test1FG1;
> GO
> ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
> ADD FILE
> (
>     NAME = test1dat3,
>     FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\t1dat3.ndf',
>     SIZE = 5MB,
>     MAXSIZE = 100MB,
>     FILEGROWTH = 5MB
> ),  
> (  
>     NAME = test1dat4,
>     FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\t1dat4.ndf',
>     SIZE = 5MB,
>     MAXSIZE = 100MB,
>     FILEGROWTH = 5MB
> )  
> TO FILEGROUP Test1FG1;
> GO
> ```

However, I have no knowledge of what any user's setup would look like (and it could potentially be Windows OR Linux, so an answer I found where the person re), but I would like to add these file group files to the DATA/ folder of the installation, or some other standard/default location. To achieve that, I tried to execute the following command:

```
ALTER DATABASE myapp_db ADD FILEGROUP data_dg

ALTER DATABASE myapp_db ADD FILE (
    NAME=data_fg,
    FILENAME='data_fg.ndf',
    SIZE=32MB,
    MAXSIZE=4096MB,
    FILEGROWTH=32MB
) TO FILEGROUP data_fg
```

However, I get the following error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: A file activation error occurred.
The physical file name 'data_fg.ndf' may be incorrect.
Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the operation.
```

Is this because SQL Server does not allow relative file paths/names for `FILEGROUP`s? (if so, why is it called `FILENAME` instead of `FILEPATH`?) What options exist for achieving this?

Comment: I'm not sure about Linux, but on Windows from SQL 2016 forward, this should give you the instance default data path - `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultDataPath') AS InstanceDefaultDataPath`.  You should be able to dynamically build the correct filename including the path.

Comment: That is correct, SQL Server does not allow relative paths. Why is it called filename? Because it is a fully-qualified filename. If they called it filepath, you'd complain that it also had a filename at the end, and so is more than just a path. Can't win. The why is largely irrelevant though - this is the way it works, for 20+ years now, whether they had what you consider to be a logical reason, went out of their way to defy your logic, or two developers rock-paper-scissored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't construct a path inside the `ALTER DATABASE` command, so you're going to have to use dynamic SQL.

If you want to just put the new data file in the default instance path, you can do as Scott suggests - use the server property for default data path:

```
DECLARE @dbname sysname = N'myapp_db';

DECLARE @path nvarchar(511) = 
  CONVERT(nvarchar(511), SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultDataPath');

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'ALTER DATABASE $db$
  ADD FILEGROUP data_fg;

ALTER DATABASE $db$ ADD FILE (
    NAME=data_fg,
    FILENAME=''data_fg.ndf'',
    SIZE=32MB,
    MAXSIZE=4096MB,
    FILEGROWTH=32MB
) TO FILEGROUP data_fg;';

SET @sql = REPLACE(REPLACE(@sql, N'$path$', @p), N'$db$', @dbname);

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

If, however, you want to base this off an existing database (maybe the one you're altering, if they pass that by a parameter), then you could do this:

```
DECLARE @dbname sysname = N'model';

DECLARE @p nvarchar(511);

;WITH x AS (SELECT TOP (1) p = physical_name, type_desc
  FROM sys.master_files
  WHERE database_id = DB_ID(@dbname)
  AND type_desc = N'ROWS'
  ORDER BY file_id
)
SELECT @p = SUBSTRING(p, 1, LEN(p)-CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(p))+1)
FROM x;

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'ALTER DATABASE $db$
  ADD FILEGROUP data_fg;

ALTER DATABASE $db$ ADD FILE (
    NAME=data_fg,
    FILENAME=''data_fg.ndf'',
    SIZE=32MB,
    MAXSIZE=4096MB,
    FILEGROWTH=32MB
) TO FILEGROUP data_fg;';

SET @sql = REPLACE(REPLACE(@sql, N'$path$', @p), N'$db$', @dbname);

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

You may even want to allow your users to override with a specific path (think of the case where the current drive is getting crowded and they want to start this new file in a totally new location).

It also strikes me as weird that you'd bother creating a data file that is only 32 MB. That's barely big enough to hold the metadata about the file, and will surely start a cycle of autogrowths as soon as it becomes active.

Comment: I'm basically adding MS-SQL support for something that used to be Oracle-only. I'm far from an expert DBA, and I'm going over the database creation. The Oracle DB definition has those size numbers defined in its creation script (and I am unaware of the reasoning behind it). I'm just "porting" it over to MS-SQL as closely as possible, but if one of those numbers doesn't make sense, I'm happy to get a fuller picture/better size values :) And last but not least, thanks a lot for your detailed/in-depth answer!!

Comment: Correction: the script was only for DB creation for dev environments, so it's not critical that the numbers are optimized. Thanks for your help anyway!